# how to update odoo One2many field from list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo

I created a method that loops over all pos orders to get data from there to use it on report, I need to display this data on an One2many field Before printing it,
I'm trying a lot but the data created on a model and doesn't displayed  on current field

here what I did,

```
data = fields.One2many(comodel_name="onepos.report.line", inverse_name="report", string="", required=False, )

def getreport(self):

    data = self.env['pos.order'].search([])
    datas=[]
    pos_dict= {}
    report= self.env['onepos.report.line'].search([])
    for rec in data:
        con = rec.config_id.name
        for line in rec.lines:
            if con in pos_dict.values():
                print('hiiiiiiiiiii')
                # total_sales = pos_dict[rec.config_id.name]
                total_sales += line.price_subtotal_incl
                res = {
                    'total': total_sales,
                    'pos': con,
                }
                datas.append(res)
            else:
                total_sales = line.price_subtotal_incl
                res2 = {
                    'total': total_sales,
                    'pos': con,
                }
                datas.append(res2)
    if datas:
        print(len(datas), )
        print(datas, )

        cntr = defaultdict(Counter)
        for d in datas:
            cntr[d['pos']].update(d)
        datas = [dict(v, **{'pos': k}) for k, v in cntr.items()]

        report.create(datas)
```

this is related model

```
class reporttotalline(models.Model):
_name = 'onepos.report.line'

pos = fields.Char(string="", required=False, )
total = fields.Char(string="", required=False, )

report = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="onepos.report", string="", required=False, )
```

how can i update the field in the current form ?

Comment: Just curious. Why you give nothing to `pos_dict` during your function get_report? you declare it but do nothing with it.

Comment: I think you have to assign value to your o2m field like this `self.data  = [(0, 0, dict )]`

Comment: And it no needs to keep temp data, you can change your model as `models.TransientModel` model.

Comment: [ORM API](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/orm.html#model-reference)

Comment: i used self.data  = [(0, 0, dict )] , and it's return error , 
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/models.py", line 4835, in _convert_to_cache
    for name, value in values.items()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items

Comment: that means you use items() method in a list object, but it belongs to a dictionary object.

Comment: I think you have to loop the list and asign the dict object to self.data each loop.like `self.data = [ (0,0,d) for d in list ]`